# Transformation Syntax for Web Application

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, web.config-transform

Do you think it's possible to use same mecanism as ['Web.config transformation'](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326%28VS.100%29.aspx) for other file (like NLog.config in my case) ?

If yes, what can I do ?

Comment: Use "SlowCheetah" Visual Studio extension. This will help you transforming any XML based configuration files (app.Config, nlog.config, etc). More information can be found here - https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5

Comment: Thanks @Nirman. Does it work with VS2015 ?

Comment: Hi Sorry for getting late on this, yes, it works well with Visual Studio 2015 as well. See the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In your VS 2015 instance, Go to Tools >> Extensions and Updates
- Search for "SlowCheetah" in "Online"
- Once found, download and install the extension
- Restart VS 2015 for changes to take effect
- Open the solution
- Right-click the XML file where you want to add the transforms, and click "Add Transform" option.

Done, you should see now transformed XML files for each configuration profile.

Comment: It works fine :) ! Thanks you very much, it's exactly what I'm looking for !

Comment: Could you just explain me difference between VS Extension and NuGet package ? I've seen SlowCheetah available in both solution ...

Comment: VS Extensions are basically for the Visual Studio IDE. They help the developers in extending Visual Studio by adding more functionalities provided by such extensions (For example, SlowCheetah, some pre-defined templates for Azure functions, etc). NuGet package becomes a part of the project, and they are mostly libraries only (like, some javascript libraries, DLLs, etc).